# Aborted restoring from back up Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

I started restoring from backup using (WITH REPLACE, RESTORE WITH RECOVERY) 
and realized that it was a mistake, so I stopped restoring.

Now this db is unavailable and has a 'Restoring' status.

- Can I expect full rollback?
- What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no rollback.  You will need to restore from the most recent backup that you have.